# React: prevent iframe from reload on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I'm building a wysiwyg on React and have to move blocks up and down. Some of my elements are dynamic, like iframe or video-player, that have some time to initialize. So when I'm changing state to move blocks - some of elements are redrawing. Is there any way to prevent this? All that changing is blocks order, but react redrawing whole element tree.

I've tried returning `false` on shouldComponentUpdate, but it didn't help.

Here is a little demo of what I mean: https://codesandbox.io/s/XDo7QO0pW
You can move blocks up&down and element that goes down will reload it's iframe.

Comment: You could move them using CSS [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead. You're looking for the `order` property on the flex-items and you could use an inline style set by react to change the ordering. I'm fairly sure that would keep them from being completely re-rendered.

Comment: Thanks, it's [working](https://codesandbox.io/s/XDo7QO0pW), but sounds a bit hacky, so I'll think if I need that at all or I can evade that by doing only static elements(like placeholders) in my wysiwyg-editor.